# How can i view the Firebase data (ListView format) in different activity?

Tags: android, firebase

i want to view all the datas in list view in another activity. no in the same activity where the data generated. check this image. [image: here the output image]

here data shows in same activity in where i inserted via firebase . i want show the list view part in another activity . how can i do that ? and how can i see the last inserted data on top? 
code for viewing data .

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseBazars.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            abc.clear();
            for( DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ADeposit ks = ds.getValue(ADeposit.class);
                abc.add(ks);
            }
            DepositList adapter = new DepositList(AdminloginEnter.this,abc);
            deposit.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

and here code for inserting data

```
 private void Add(){


    String dt= ki.getText().toString().trim();
    String ct = costt.getText().toString().trim();
    String nm = spn.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(dt)){
        String id= databaseBazars.push().getKey();
        ADeposit bz= new ADeposit(id,nm,ct,dt);
        databaseBazars.child(id).setValue(bz);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Valid Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

and here is the deposit list class .

```
import com.sonalirod.alwayswhite.Model.ADeposit;


import java.util.List;

public class DepositList extends ArrayAdapter<ADeposit> {
    private Activity context;
    private List<ADeposit> abc;

    public DepositList(Activity context,List<ADeposit>abc){
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout_deposit,abc);
        this.context=context;
        this.abc=abc;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View ListViewItem= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_deposit,null,true);
        TextView texviewname=(TextView) ListViewItem.findViewById(R.id.namet);
        TextView textviewcost=(TextView) ListViewItem.findViewById(R.id.amountt);
        TextView textviewdate =(TextView) ListViewItem.findViewById(R.id.datu);


        ADeposit ad  = abc.get(position);

        texviewname.setText(ad.getName());
        textviewcost.setText(ad.getAmount());
        textviewdate.setText(ad.getDat());
        return ListViewItem;
    }
}
```

who helps for the viewing from firebase. if anyone want i can provide the model class also . but my code is perfectly work. i just want to know **how can i show that list view  in another activity ** also how can i see the last inserted data on first(upper) place .

Comment: retrieve the list from the database in another activity

Comment: well, i have to do the same code again?

Comment: yes retrieve them in the other activity using listener, since you dont want them in the first activity then just retrieve them in the second

Comment: do you know anything about sorting? i mean the last inserted data on last .

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data in the other activity, you need to use a listener there example `valueEventListener`, to sort the data do this:

```
 //inside onDatachange or onChildAdded
  String inputs= dataSnapshot.child("ks").getValue().toString();
                 arraylist.add(inputs);
                 HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
                 hashSet.addAll(arraylist);
                 arraylist.clear();
                 arraylist.addAll(hashSet);

                 //Alphabetic sorting.
                 Collections.sort(editlists);
                adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist);

                 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

First retrieve the add normally, add them to your `arraylist` then you will be able to use `HashSet` to sort it (last item added will be in on last)

Comment: bro i have a problem . here arraylist showing red . i don't need alphabate sorting i just need . last inserted datas on first place . if you take a look on the image then you can get it. i want the "Nayon" parts data (which is last inserted )on the top .i mean upper than the "Saikat" part.

Comment: @Meeyan if this answered your question, please upvote it then and mark it as correct, to mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.